# How to test a method which uses caller in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I have a private method which returns something based on the caller method:

```
private
def aPrivateMethod
  r = nil
  caller_method = caller[0][/`([^']*)'/, 1]

  case caller_method
     when "method_1"
        r = "I was called by method_1"
     when "method_2"
        r = "I was called by method_2"
  end

  return r
end
```

When writing the test unit the method name calling this private method will not be method_1 nor method_2, it will be something beginning with test and I cannot find a solution to return a pass from the test.

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do something like this --- I've never had the urge to test which object is calling another.  Seems to me that if this matters, then the code under test is too closely coupled, or needs refactoring to allow straightforward unit testing.

Comment: Most probably the code will need refactoring but in it's incipient state I cannot see how. Don't ask why. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a proxy method in your test class for this purpose

```
def method_1 *args
  aPrivateMethod *args
end
```

And then call this method from your test.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex in the case expression:

```
def aPrivateMethod
  caller_method = caller[0][/`([^']*)'/, 1]

  case caller_method
     when "method_1"
        "I was called by method_1"
     when "method_2"
        "I was called by method_2"
     when /^test_\d+/
        "test call from #{caller_method}"
     else nil
  end
end
```

Also, you had a lot of superfluous code in there... the r variable is not needed at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code referring to r and other code lines for that matter, have become like a "standard" and I am impelled to use it.